# How to send socket messages via Django views when socket server and views.py are split into two files?

Tags: django, python-3.x, sockets

Env: Python 3.6, and Django 2.1

I have created a Django website and a socket server, and files are organized like this:

- web

  - ...
  - user (a Django app)

    - `__init__.py`
    - views.py
    - ...
  - server.py

Actually I want to build a umbrella rental system by using django, and server connects to umbrella shelf via multi-thread socket (sending some messages). Like I press the borrow button, and `views.py` can call the server test_function and send some messages to the connected umbrella shelf.

I can import server variables or functions in `views.py`, but I cannot get the right answer while `server.py` is running. So I want to ask you if you could give me some advice. Thanks a lot!

By the way, I tried to import the global variable `clients` directly in `views.py`, but still got `[]`.

`server.py` defines a multi-thread server, which is basically as below:

```py
clients = []

class StuckThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get('name', '')

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # do something

    def func1(self):
        # do something


def test_function(thread_name):
    # if the function is called by `views.py`, then `clients = []` and return 'nothing', but if I call this function in `server.py`, then I can get a wanted result, which is `got the thread`
    for client in clients:
        if client['thread'].name == thread_name:
            return 'got the thread'
    return 'nothing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip_port = ('0.0.0.0', 65432)
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind(ip_port)
    server.listen(max_listen_num)
    while True:
        client, address = socket.accept()
        param = {'name': 'test name'}
        stuck_thread = StuckThread(**param)
        clients.append({"client": client, "address": address, "thread": stuck_thread})
        stuck_thread.start()
```

and I have a Django `views.py` like this

```py
def view_function(request):
    from server import clients
    print(clients) # got []
    form server import test_function
    print(test_function('test name')) # got 'nothing'
    return render(request, 'something.html')
```

Comment: Could redis database solve this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem by socket communication between django views.py and server.py. I open another port to receive messages from views.py. Once the borrow button  is pressed, a socket client in views.py will build up and send arguments and other messages to the server.